Column Headings on Excel UserForm ComboBox
I have created a UserForm in Excel and added a 4-column ComboBox to it.  The ComboBox is populated using an array derived from a SQL query, as the contents can vary each time.  Is there a way to set the Column Headings on the ComboBox as two of the columns show a Yes/No value and so the user won't know what they represent?
This is the code I am using to create the array and ComboBox:
' Get Customers
ReDim CustArray(res.RecordCount, 3)
res.MoveFirst
i = 0
Do Until res.EOF
    Set rst = ReadDB(strQuery)
    CustArray(i, 0) = rst.Fields(0).Value
    CustArray(i, 1) = rst.Fields(1).Value
    CustArray(i, 2) = rst.Fields(2).Value
    CustArray(i, 3) = rst.Fields(3).Value
    res.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Loop
With cbx_Customers
    .ColumnCount = 4
    .ColumnWidths = "48;180;48;65"
    .List = CustArray
End With


You can't use the built-in columnheads property unless you put the data into a range on a sheet. Also, it would be faster to use GetRows to load the data into an array, then assign it to the Column property of the combobox.

Thanks for the info. Rory.  Was aware of the GetRows function, but as the most it is going to return is about 20 rows not sure there would be a measurable speed increase from the users point (but I will try it).  Guess the only option would be to paste the SQL results into a hidden sheet and then create the combobox from that.

As ColumnHeads have the same restriction as well in combos as in listboxes, you might find some useful ideas in post Creating multi-column listbox with headers ... @SteveBrown
